# SapUI5 Grid Table Column Auto Width Issue

Tags: sapui5

I'm using sap.ui.table component and I would like to set the column width value "auto" depending on cell content value's width. But I couldn't make it. How can I set auto width columns ?

Here is a part of my code and screenshot;

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                label: new sap.m.Label({
                    text: json[i].Value,
                }),
                template: new sap.m.Text({
                    text: '{' + json[i].Key + '}',
                    wrapping : false,
                    textAlign : sap.ui.core.TextAlign.Begin,
                }),
                sortProperty: json[i].Key,
                filterProperty: json[i].Key,
                width : 'auto',
                resizable : false,
                flexible : false,
                //enableGrouping : json[i].enableGrouping,
                //visible : json[i].visible,
            }));
            oTable.autoResizeColumn(i);})
```

Here is the result image;

https://ibb.co/h4BMSR

Comment: Have you tried `sap.m.Table` with [`fixedLayout="false"`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Table/methods/getFixedLayout)? "When this property is set to false, sap.m.Table is rendered with auto layout algorithm. This means, the width of the table and its cells depends on the contents of the cells."

Comment: @PéterCataño I used that sap.m.Table before. But when I used this I can't use column filtering by clicking column header. I think it's not supported. fixedLayout="false" works properly only with sap.m.table.

Comment: @MLE ui5 version?

Comment: @Skay  ui5 version is 2.0

Comment: @MLE interesting, latest released is 1.50

Comment: @Skay, I found this related with my issue. But it doesn't work. http://jsbin.com/vekedumita/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I'm trying to solve this issue for two days :). I tried many different ways. But I couldn't do that. I don't know how to do ?

Comment: Am I using that coding wrong ? `var list = _this.getView().byId("PersonnelListTable_id");
          var cols = list.getColumns();
          for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
              list.autoResizeColumn(cols[i]);
          }`

Comment: this happens because table internally has ```table-layout: fixed;``` which changes the default behaviour of the browser when it calculates cell width. I will try to reach control developers for this particular control and ask them if there is any reason for this property in CSS. As a workaround you can redefine global style: ```.sapUiTableCtrl { table-layout: auto !important; }```

Comment: I know it. I tried to edit using css code. But the main issue is table headers and rows are different table objects. When I changed the cell's width (removing by fixed layout etc..) table headers don't change. They don't affect.

Comment: If you can inspect the whole table component in browser devtool. You can easly aware that has two different table object.

Comment: When I used the sap.m.table there is no issue about with this situation. fixedLayout property solves that issue. But in sap.ui.table has no fixedLayout property. There are some differences between them

Comment: Here is the final result https://ibb.co/fsi7mm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment it's not possible for `sap.ui.table.Table`.

Default layout for table is "fixed" and can not be changed via any API settings for this control. When new records are loaded, the content of the cells might have different length, thus it would lead columns to jump when scrolling.

`sap.ui.table.Column` has property `resizable` which allows user to resize the column. In addition to this, there is property `autoResizable` which can adjust column width based on the currently visible data by double clicking on columns separator (see docs -
 https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Column).

Comment: I think I should use responsive table component. sap.ui.table.Column doesn't benefit my business. Thank you for your help @Skay